# How do I slide the videos if I click on next button using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I able to embed the 4 videos in a particular div using "angular.js".But,I have so many videos nearly 20.

So,what I'm trying to do is,on click of "Next" button should get next 4 videos in a same div.How can I achieve this?

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

My html code:

```
<div class="panel-body">

                <video width=176 height=99 style=" margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;"
                    ng-repeat="videoSource in videoSources track by $index" autoplay
                    controls ng-src="{{videoSource | trustUrl}}">
                </video>
                <br> <a href="#" ng-click='loadVideos()'>Load videos</a>
                <br><button type="button">Next</button>

            </div>
```

My js code:

```
angular.module('Admin', [])
.controller('Home', function($scope) {

    $scope.videoSources = [];

    $scope.loadVideos = function() {
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://54.88.118.248/Video/Digital_Hiring.mp4');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://54.88.118.248/Video/Customer_Service.mp4');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://54.88.118.248/Video/Digital_Hiring.mp4');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://54.88.118.248/Video/Digital_Hiring.mp4');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://54.88.118.248/Video/Customer_Service.mp4');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://54.88.118.248/Video/Digital_Hiring.mp4');
    };
})
.filter("trustUrl", ['$sce',
                     function($sce) {
                       return function(recordingUrl) {
                         return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
                       };
                     }
                   ]);
```

Comment: I recomment using bootstrap's carousel - http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

But if you want an angular solution (with popping, not sliding), add for each video a variable "page" and just filter {page: 0} {page: 1} and so on.. should be very easy, but with no animation effect.

Comment: Can you please edit the code over here regarding angular.js since I'm a beginner to angular.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual Angular way would be to create a custom filter to paginate the results. In the example, I've created a `paginate` filter that takes two parameters: `pageNum` and `pageSize` to `slice` the input array into the required chunk without any pre-processing of the array required.

Also added the necessary `next` and `previous` buttons and hid the `load videos` button.

```js
angular.module('Admin', [])
  .controller('Home', function($scope) {

    $scope.pageNum = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 4;
    $scope.isFirstPage = function() {
      return $scope.pageNum === 0;
    };
    $scope.isLastPage = function() {
      return $scope.pageNum >= Math.floor($scope.videoSources.length / $scope.pageSize);
    };
    $scope.prevPage = function() {
      $scope.pageNum--;
    };
    $scope.nextPage = function() {
      $scope.pageNum++;
    };

    $scope.videoSources = [];
    $scope.loadVideos = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/boat_149.webm');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/horse_riding_205.webm');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/flower_124.webm');
      }
    };
  })
  .filter("trustUrl", ['$sce',
    function($sce) {
      return function(recordingUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
      };
    }
  ])
  .filter('paginate', function() {
    console.log('creating paginate function', arguments);
    return function(inputArray, pageNumber, pageSize) {
      console.log('paginating', arguments);
      pageNumber = pageNumber || 0;
      pageSize = pageSize || 4;
      if (!Array.isArray(inputArray)) return inputArray;
      return inputArray.slice(pageNumber * pageSize, (pageNumber + 1) * pageSize);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="Admin" ng-controller="Home">
  <video width=176 height=99 ng-repeat="videoSource in videoSources | paginate:pageNum:pageSize track by $index" autoplay controls ng-src="{{videoSource | trustUrl}}">
  </video>
  <div ng-show="videoSources.length">
    <button ng-disabled="isFirstPage()" ng-click="prevPage()">Previous</button>
    <button ng-disabled="isLastPage()" ng-click="nextPage()">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="videoSources.length">
    <a href="#" ng-click='loadVideos()'>Load videos</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And because I felt like playing around with the code some more, here's a version that makes a pagination object, so that the functionality can be reused in different controllers and directives:

```js
angular.module('Admin', [])
  .controller('Home', function($scope, Pagination) {
    $scope.videoSources = [];
    $scope.pagination = new Pagination(4);

    $scope.loadVideos = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/boat_149.webm');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/horse_riding_205.webm');
        $scope.videoSources.push('http://images.all-free-download.com/footage_preview/webm/flower_124.webm');
      }
    };
  })
  .factory('Pagination', function() {
   var Pagination = function(pageSize) {
     this.pageSize = pageSize || 4;
      this.pageNum = 0;
      this.sourceLength = 0;
    };
    Pagination.prototype.isFirstPage = function() {
      return this.pageNum === 0;
    };
    Pagination.prototype.isLastPage = function(sourceLength) {
      return this.pageNum >= Math.floor((sourceLength || this.sourceLength) / this.pageSize);
    };
    Pagination.prototype.prevPage = function() {
      this.pageNum--;
    };
    Pagination.prototype.nextPage = function() {
      this.pageNum++;
    };
    Pagination.prototype.setPage = function(pageNum) {
     this.pageNum = pageNum;
    };
    Pagination.prototype.setPageSize = function(pageSize) {
     this.pageSize = pageSize;
    };
    Pagination.prototype.setSourceLength = function(sourceLength) {
     this.sourceLength = sourceLength;
    }
    Pagination.prototype.getPage = function() { return this.pageNum; };
    Pagination.prototype.getPageSize = function() { return this.pageSize; };
    Pagination.prototype.getSourceLength = function() { return this.sourceLength; };
    return Pagination;
  })
  .filter("trustUrl", ['$sce',
    function($sce) {
      return function(recordingUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
      };
    }
  ])
  .filter('paginate', function() {
    console.log('creating paginate function', arguments);
    return function(inputArray, pageNumber, pageSize) {
      console.log('paginating', arguments);
      pageNumber = pageNumber || 0;
      pageSize = pageSize || 4;
      if (pageNumber && pageNumber.pageSize) pageSize = pageNumber.pageSize;
      if (pageNumber && pageNumber.pageNum !== undefined) pageNumber = pageNumber.pageNum;
      if (!Array.isArray(inputArray)) return inputArray;
      return inputArray.slice(pageNumber * pageSize, (pageNumber + 1) * pageSize);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="Admin" ng-controller="Home">
  <video width=176 height=99 ng-repeat="videoSource in videoSources | paginate:pagination track by $index" autoplay controls ng-src="{{videoSource | trustUrl}}">
  </video>
  <div ng-show="videoSources.length">
    <button ng-disabled="pagination.isFirstPage()" ng-click="pagination.prevPage()">Previous</button>
    <button ng-disabled="pagination.isLastPage(videoSources.length)" ng-click="pagination.nextPage()">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-hide="videoSources.length">
    <a href="#" ng-click='loadVideos()'>Load videos</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The filter now looks a bit stranger, because I wanted to keep the option to use it as `paginate:pageNumber:pageSize` but also allow it to be used as `paginate:paginationObject` and that took a little trickery. But now, our pagination functionality is abstracted away into a factory so it can be reused and keep our controller lean, and that is the *Angular Way*(TM) :D

**Edit:** Extra `paginate` filter explanation:

```
  .filter('paginate', function() {
```

a `console.log()` call I used to debug that I forgot in here

```
    console.log('creating paginate function', arguments);
```

To be able to accept parameters in an Angular filter, you have to return a function that needs those parameters from the filter function

```
    return function(inputArray, pageNumber, pageSize) {
```

Another debugging `console.log()` call

```
      console.log('paginating', arguments);
```

We can't be sure the parameters were passed in, so we provide sensible defaults (in this case, if `pageNumber` wasn't given, we'll set it to 0 and if `pageSize` wasn't given, we'll set it to 4)

```
      pageNumber = pageNumber || 0;
      pageSize = pageSize || 4;
```

Because we want to be able to pass in a `Pagination` object as a parameter instead of a page number & page size, we see if the first parameter isn't by chance an *object* containing `pageSize` and/or `pageNum` members, and if it is, we set the local `pageNumber` and `pageSize` variables to the values of the `Pagination` object's members

```
      if (pageNumber && pageNumber.pageSize) pageSize = pageNumber.pageSize;
      if (pageNumber && pageNumber.pageNum !== undefined) pageNumber = pageNumber.pageNum;
```

Then we check to see if the first parameter to the filter (the value being filtered) is actually an array. If it isn't, we just return the value unchanged. For example, if we were to have `{{ 1 | paginate }}` in an Angular template, the result would be `1`, our algorithm wouldn't break. If it's an array, though, such as `{{ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | paginate }}` (with default `paginate` parameters) it would become `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `{{ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | paginate:0:2 }}` would become `[1, 2]`.

```
      if (!Array.isArray(inputArray)) return inputArray;
```

And then the actual pagination logic (funny how it's way smaller than the input checking part of the code). We `slice` the input array to start at index `pageNumber * pageSize` and to end at index `(pageNumber + 1) * pageSize` (non-inclusive). Think of the first page (for pageSize = 4) having page number 0 and starting at index 0 and finishing at index 3 (so ending at index 4 (= 1 * 4) non-inclusive), page two having page number 1 and starting at index 4 (= 1 * 4) and finishing at index 7 (index 8 (= 2 * 4) non-inclusive, and so on. [More information on `Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
      return inputArray.slice(pageNumber * pageSize, (pageNumber + 1) * pageSize);
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Lonut.

Comment: Can you please explain the paginate filter function

Comment: Here you go. Hope it clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Without sliding effect, you can do it with pages:

Change loading videos:

```
$scope.videoSources.push({url:'video_here');
```

Then, page them:

```
var page = 1, perpage = 4;
$.each($scope.videoSources, function(k, v) {
   v.page = (page++)/perpage;
```

Now that we have pages, in your HTML you can filter your data:

```
ng-repeat="video in videoSources | filter: {page: current_page}"
```

And next page ng-click:

```
ng-click="current_page++"
```

Same for previous page.

**Important noticing: because I changed your array to contain objects, to access the video you need to use video.url in your ng-src